# Radio button animation not working in ie11 or edge

Tags: css, radio-button, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Ive creating a radio list animation which works in all browsers excluding ie11 and edge. I’ve searched for solutions online but have been unable to fix this compatibility issue. I’m hoping someone will be able to provide a solution with explanation. I’ve included all of the code below.

```css
.vertical-radio-buttons div {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
  clear: both
}

.vertical-radio-buttons span {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0.8rem;
  cursor: inherit;
}

.vertical-radio-buttons label {
  font-size: rem-calc(16);
}

.vertical-radio-buttons input {
  float: left;
  width: 0.8rem;
  margin-left: -.08rem;
}

fieldset {
  border-color: transparent;
}


/*new*/

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: verdana;
}

label {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

input[type="radio"] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input [type="radio"]::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .1s;
}


/* type_1 */

.type_1 {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.type_1:after {
  border: 5px solid goldenrod;
  transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
}

.type_1:checked:after {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}


/* type_2 */

.type_2 {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.type_2:after {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(0, 0);
}

.type_2:checked:after {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-radio-buttons">
  <fieldset>
    <form>
      <div><span><input class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1" checked><label for=""> How about once a week? Let's take it slow</label></span></div>
      <div><span><input class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1"><label for=""> How about a few times a month? Sound about right?</label></span></div>
      <div><span><input class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1"><label for=""> Once a month? I'd be okay with that. OK.</label></span></div>
      <div><span><input class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1"><label for=""> It's not you. It's me. How about a small break? 30-Days?</label></span></div>
      <div><span><input class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1"><label for=""> Unsubscribe? Are you sure it's over? "Sniff"</label></span></div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is not supposed to generate pseudo elements, the `:after` pseudo element renders badly in IE and Edge. You should use `:checked` and `:not(:checked)` to custom your radio button. I made a sample and you could check it, it also works well in IE and Edge:

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    content: '';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: goldenrod;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s;
    transition: all .1s;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(50%, 50%, 0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>
       <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
       <label for="test1">One</label>
    </p>
    <p>
       <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
       <label for="test2">Two</label>
    </p>
       <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
       <label for="test3">Three</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

to restyle an `input`, the best is usually to use the `label` linked with it via the `for` attribute. *You almost did it*.

It avoids to deal with browserS's behavior.

first is to add an id to each inputs and use that `id` value for the `for` attribute's value, then the `input` can be hidden and a pseudo drawn with style.

example with `box-shadow` to mimic your style effects since a pseudo from the label is used. It also reduce the code involved for the animation.

```css
div {
  /* increase line or margin ? */
  line-height: 1.8em;
  margin: 0.25em 1em;
}

div span input {
  /* hide it */
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

input+label::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 1em 1em 0 6px white, inset 0 0 0 15px goldenrod, 0 0 0 ;/* you can add as many , could be rings Inside each others*/
  transition: 0.2s
}

input:checked+label:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px white, inset 0 0 0 15px goldenrod, 0 0 3px ;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
          <input id="_1" class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1" checked >
          <label for="_1"> How about once using fully that label</label></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
          <input id="_2" class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1"  >
          <label for="_2"> How about styling that label too ?</label></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>
          <input id="_3" class="type_1" type="radio" name="option1"  >
          <label for="_3"> How about cool is the <code>for</code> attribute ?</label></span>
</div>
```